# Using find{ } on a map where the whole map is evaluated not each element

Tags: groovy

I created some mixin methods. Code and example below:

```
URL.metaClass.withCreds = { u, p ->
    delegate.openConnection().tap {
        setRequestProperty('Authorization', "Basic ${(u + ':' + p).bytes.encodeBase64()}")
    }
}

URLConnection.metaClass.fetchJson = {
    delegate.setRequestProperty('Accept', 'application/json')
    delegate.connect()
    def code = delegate.responseCode
    def result = new JsonSlurper().parse(code >= 400 ? delegate.errorStream : delegate.inputStream as InputStream)
    [
            ok  : code in (200..299),
            body: result,
            code: code
    ]

}
```

example usage:

```
new URL("$baseUrl/projects/$name").withCreds(u, p).fetchJson().find {
        it.ok
    }?.tap{
        it.repos = getRepos(it.key).collectEntries { [(it.slug): it] }
    }
}
```

When I **dont use** find(), my object is, as expected, a map with those 3 elements. When I use find `it` is a Map.Entry with key `ok` and value `true`

which produces this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ok for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
Possible solutions: key
```

It occured to me when I wrote this post that it was treated the map as an iterable and thus looking at every entry which I have subsequently verified. How do I `find` on the whole map? I want `it.ok` because if it's true, I need to carry it forward

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in Groovy SDK. `Map.find()` runs over an entry set of the map you call method on. Based on expectation you have defined I'm guessing you are looking for a function that tests map with a given predicate and returns the map if it matches the predicate. You may add a function that does to through `Map.metaClass` (since you already add methods to `URL` and `URLConnection` classes). Consider following example:

```groovy
Map.metaClass.continueIf = { Closure<Boolean> predicate ->
    predicate(delegate) ? delegate : null
}

def map = [
        ok  : true,
        body: '{"message": "ok"}',
        code: 200
]

map.continueIf { it.ok }?.tap {
    it.repos = "something"
}

println map
```

In this example we introduced a new method `Map.continueIf(predicate)` that tests if map matches given predicate and returns a `null` otherwise. Running above example produces following output:

```
[ok:true, body:{"message": "ok"}, code:200, repos:something]
```

If predicate is not met, `map` does not get modified.

Alternatively, for more strict design, you could make `fetchJson()` method returning an object with corresponding `onSuccess()` and `onError()` methods so you can express more clearly that you add `repos` when you get a successful response and optionally you create an error response otherwise.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I actually ended up doing pretty much that: `map.with{ it.ok ? it : null}?.tap{}`